# Copy file from sub subfolder to another directory

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a folder, it have subfolders and one subfodler on it, in the last subfolder, inside it have picture. Something like this.
.

```
FolderMaster
|--chicken
|    |--pic
|        |--NiceChicken.png
|--cow
|    |--pic
|         |--NiceCow.png
|--bird
    |--pic
         |--NiceBird.png
```

.
It is possible to copy all the *.png (i want the picture only) from pic folder (since every subfolder of 'FolderMaster' have same subfolder, which is 'pic') to another folder/directory outside of 'FolderMaster', let's just call ii 'FolderOther' ?
Im thingking of recursive method but haven't an idea of it.
I trying this, but it seems my method not working. Since it give me 'Parse Error'.
.

```
for /D %%A in ("E:\Picturez\test11\FolderMaster") do (
  for /D %%B in ("%%~fA\*") do (
    for /D %%C in ("%%~fB\pic") do (
    xcopy /L /I "%%~fC\*.png" E:\Picturez\test22\FolderOther"
  )
)
)
```

.
Maybe someone could help me on this. I do this in win 8.1, write it on .bat file, incase this info could help.

Comment: Besides the typo in the `xcopy` line (missing `"`), there is no need to loop through one dedicated folder (like `FolderMaster` and `pic`), since the only dynamic folders are the ones in between…

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious issue with your provided script is that you have unbalanced doublequotes on your 4th line.

```batch-file
@Echo Off
For /D %%A In ("E:\Picturez\test11\FolderMaster") Do (
    For /D %%B In ("%%~A\*") Do (
        For /D %%C In ("%%B\pic") Do (
            XCopy /L /I "%%~C\*.png" "E:\Picturez\test22\FolderOther"
        )
    )
)
```

However, you could tidy that a little to:

```batch-file
@For /D %%A In ("E:\Picturez\test11\FolderMaster"
) Do @For /D %%B In ("%%~A\*"
) Do @For /D %%C In ("%%B\pic"
) Do @XCopy /L /I "%%~C\*.png" "E:\Picturez\test22\FolderOther"
```

Or better still shorten it to:

```batch-file
@For /D %%A In ("E:\Picturez\test11\FolderMaster\*"
) Do @For /D %%B In ("%%A\pic"
) Do @XCopy /L /I "%%~B\*.png" "E:\Picturez\test22\FolderOther"
```

Which could be further shortened to:

```batch-file
@For /D %%A In ("E:\Picturez\test11\FolderMaster\*"
) Do @XCopy /L /I "%%A\pic\*.png" "E:\Picturez\test22\FolderOther"
```

Once you're happy with the output you'd obviously remove the `/L` option from the `XCopy` command.

---

And finally, if those are the only png files within the target tree, the following may prove just as useful to you:

```batch-file
@For /R "E:\Picturez\test11\FolderMaster" %%A In ("*.png"
) Do @Echo=Copy /Y "%%A" "E:\Picturez\test22\FolderOther"
```

In this last example you'd remove the `Echo=` when you're happy with the output.

Comment: Although I like the step-by-step  approach to come to the optimal solution (the last `xcopy` one), I do not agree with your interpretation of "tidy"; from the readability point of view, your first code snippet is the best one, don't you think? fewer lines do not necessarily make better code…

Comment: By tidy @aschipfl, I meant the removal of unnecessary parentheses, the fact that it makes fewer lines is just a side effect of that. To specifically answer your question though, no, I prefer all of them over the first one. I don't see a need to open a parenthesized block unless, more than one thing is happening within it, or it is conditional and the other condition is to follow it.